# Splitting the sum $(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i)^2$

Tags: summation, induction

Hello Mathematics Community,

I am trying to split the sum $(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i)^2$

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i \right)^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} i \right)^2 + \left(\sum_{n+1}^{n+1} n + 1 \right)^2$$

But I get wrong results for $n=1$.
Can somebody show me where my mistake is?

sincerely,
M.Hisoka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i + \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+1}i$$

meaning that

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} i + \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+1}i\right)^2$$

sure, but since $(a+b)^2\neq a^2+b^2$, your inequality is also false.

Comment: Such a silly mistake of mine. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @M.Hisoka Yeah, it's a bit silly, but it happens :)